# I will try to print 100 of circle and make them go anywhere on the screen

Tags: javascript, class, canvas, html5-canvas

```
class Circle {
    constructor(x, y, dx, dy, radius) {
        this.x = x
        this.y = y
        this.dx = dx
        this.dy = dy
        this.radius = radius
    }

    draw() {
        c.beginPath()
        c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        c.strokeStyle = "blue"
        c.stroke()

    }

    update() {
        if (this.x + this.radius > innerWidth || this.x - this.radius < 0) {
            this.dx = - this.dx
        }
        if (this.y + this.radius > innerHeight || this.y - this.radius < 0) {
            this.dy = -this.dy
        }

        this.x += this.dx
        this.y -= this.dy
        circleArray.draw()
    }
}

let circleArray = []
// let circle = [];
for (let i = 0  ; i < 100; i++){
    let radius = 30
    let x = Math.random() * innerWidth
    let y = Math.random() * innerHeight
    let dx = (Math.random() - 0.5 * 5)
    let dy = (Math.random() - 0.5 * 5)
    // circle = new Circle(x,y,dx,dy,radius)
    circleArray =(new Circle(x,y,dx,dy,radius))
    console.log(circleArray)
    // console.log(circleArray)
}


function animation() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animation)
    c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

    for(let i = 0;i < circleArray.length; i++){
        circleArray[i].update()
        // console.log(circle[i])
    }
}

animation()
```

i will try to print 100 circle by using html canvas and Class in javascript but nothing happend
then i try to push new class in empty array they give me a error and them i call dray method with empyt array variable the give a error and say this is not a function and them i try to use both
empty array and a new variable so they give me a typeerror and say this is undefind

Comment: `circleArray`  is an Array, it doesn't have a `.draw()` method, you probably meant `this.draw()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues in your snippet:

1. `circleArray =(new Circle(x,y,dx,dy,radius))`

This assigns a single circle instance to the `circleArray` variable. You probably meant to write `circleArray.push(new Circle(...))`

2. circleArray.draw()

This might have worked because of the mistake in (1), but should now be `this.draw()` instead.

Here's a snippet that has these issues fixed:

```js
const innerWidth = 256;
const innerHeight = 256;
const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
cvs.width = 256;
cvs.height = 256;
const c = cvs.getContext("2d");

class Circle {
  constructor(x, y, dx, dy, radius) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.dx = dx
    this.dy = dy
    this.radius = radius
  }

  draw() {
    c.beginPath()
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    c.strokeStyle = "blue"
    c.stroke()
  }

  update() {
    if (this.x + this.radius > innerWidth || this.x - this.radius < 0) {
      this.dx = -this.dx
    }
    if (this.y + this.radius > innerHeight || this.y - this.radius < 0) {
      this.dy = -this.dy
    }

    this.x += this.dx
    this.y -= this.dy
    this.draw();
  }
}

let circleArray = []
// let circle = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  let radius = 30
  let x = Math.random() * innerWidth
  let y = Math.random() * innerHeight
  let dx = (Math.random() - 0.5 * 5)
  let dy = (Math.random() - 0.5 * 5)
  circleArray.push(new Circle(x, y, dx, dy, radius))
}


function animation() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animation)
  c.clearRect(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)

  for (let i = 0; i < circleArray.length; i++) {
    circleArray[i].update()
  }
}

document.body.appendChild(cvs);
animation();
```